Автоматическое создание дверного проема Unreal Engine 5

хочу сделать так что бы при перемещении двери в каких либо объекта автоматически создавался дверной проём, что бы каждый раз не вырезать его в объектах, типа как meshboolean в режиме моделирования, возможно ли это сделать вообще?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
